# .Net multiple application product - Automatic installer feasibility

Tags: .net, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a complexe installation scenario where there is an important user interaction need. 
Here are the list of features that I need to support in installation process :

1. Let user identify a data base and data table that will be used as the knowledge base in my product
2. Let user map the columns of knowledge base data table toward expected columns
3. Create a new sql data base which will communicate with the data base identified in step 1
4. Install a WPF desktop application
5. Install a windows service
6. Install a new web site

I've never developed an installation package and I want to know whether an existing packaging program 
can help me create such an installation package.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want an MSI-based setup,so:

The last three items on your list are fairly straightforward. Practically all reasonable installer tools that generate MSI setups (I'm not including Visual Studio installer projects in that) have good support for them. They are normal installation tasks.

The first three are more complicated. There's a line between application install and application configuration, and those first three belong to app configuration and should be done in a separate app the first time the app runs because it'll be easier to build and debug outside the install; the user may want to take a break and save what's done so far; the user may choose to rerun it (and you can't rerun the install). Also the native MSI dialogs aren't very rich, and the complications of the Next/Back/Cancel UI wizard steps and integrating your code will be a steep learning curve; the UI sequence isn't elevated (it's designed for collecting data) so if you need admin privilege there you will be stuck. if your clients ever require a silent install then you'll need to figure out how to pass all that data on the command line. Also, the protocol is that you don't modify the system in the UI sequence (because it might fail or be canceled and there is no recovery that cleans it up, unlike the execute sequence of an MSI install).

So I'd start with one of the full strength install tools on those last three items while you get up to speed on how UI works, but in all likelihood you'll decide that you want a custom UI written in managed code/WPF or soomething like that for those first three steps, and separating it from the install will be more reliable.

Comment: Thank you PhilDW. I will try to write a custom manager for three first steps and try to lunch the installer once the three first items are configured via the manager.